# Short form of if/else in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, ternary-operator

How can i write this if/else expression in short form using ternary operator ?

```
int value1 = 5,value2 = 0;
if (value2 == 0) {
} else {
   value1 = value1 / value2;
}
```

Comment: You have no "if" part, so why would you want a ternary operator here? And using that doesn't even improve your code quality. Just invert the condition and use a single "if" instead.

Comment: What action do you take on first "if"?

Comment: this code makes no sense as the `if (value2 == 0)`condition is always true as value2 is initialized to 0. The else statement is never reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to take any action on `value` if `value2` is 0, so you can write a ternary operator that assigns `value1` to `value1` if `value2` is 0, and `value1 / value2` otherwise, e.g.:

```
value1 = value2 != 0 ? value1 / value2 : value1;
```

Answer (score 3):

the simplest way is just invert condition and using `if` statement only:

```
if(value2 != 0) {
  value1 = value1 / value2;
}
```

Comment: This is not a ternary operator as OP asked to rewrite if/else to ternary operator.

Comment: @steven yes, sir. but I think it is unnecessary to using a ternary operator. so I come up it with the "simplest way".

Comment: Fair enough ;) Ternary can be hard to read as @GhostCat already pointed out.

Comment: If the op has to do homework, then he shall solve this simple thing himself. If he is interested in the "better" solution to be used in the real world,  he can find it here.

Comment: @GhostCat good idea, sir!  if OP limited to using ternary operator in his homework, then DarshanMehta's answer is meet his needs.

Answer (score 0):

ternary operator syntax is

```
condition?true statement:false satatement;
```

for your code use

```
value2 == 0? : value1 / value2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use ternary operator

```
value1 = value2 == 0 ? value2 : value1 / value2;
```